# How to add "formControlName" to angular reactive forms "formGroup" from child components?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I have dynamic components in form and I want to connect fields with angular reactive forms.

for example we have

first-component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myform">
...
   <second-component></second-component>
...
   <button type="submit">
</form>
```

second-component.html

```
<div ngFor ...>
...
   <third-component></third-component>
...
</div>
```

third-component.html

```
<div>
...
   <input type="text">
...
</div>
```

How to add "FormControlName" in third component, that is field?

Comment: You should pass the formGroup as @input to the child components, and then before the html input specify the relative formGroup.

Comment: Another method is that you specify the formControl itself, like this: 
<input [formControl]="formGroup.get('inputName')" type text>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the formGroup as @input to the child components, and then before the html input specify the relative formGroup

Another method is that you specify the formControl itself, like this:

```
<input [formControl]="formGroup.get('inputName')" type text>
```

See this link for more information on the topic:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form